# How to generate randomized height 3d model from .svg points and automate it?

Tags: modeling

I am just a newbie in blender area and i want to make some project about city shapes that i have in svg format. my svg image has point to point boundaries and i can make it 3d them in blender then automate for thousands of it . but i dont know how to make them 3d with random height from their svg path points .so i can generate some fun stuff and maybe give them shapes like diamond ? who knows ? maybe you can help me make it and automate with some python script. because i have more than one city.Thanks a lot .
[image]

Comment: do you want to have mesh objects or should it still be a curve?

Comment: @Chris mesh objects would be good